# Using KeyedDataSource to load data from local db in Pagination library without room

Tags: android, android-paging

I want to load **1000 records** in **pagination** from local **database**. I am able to load initial records by setting limit on query but consecutive records are not getting loaded on list scroll.

I am getting data from `DataSource` in `PagedList` as below:

```
  PagedList pagedList = new PagedList.Builder<Integer, ModelClass>()
            .setConfig(new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setPageSize(50)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .build())
            .setDataSource(new DataClassKeyed())
            .setMainThreadExecutor(new MainThreadExecutor())
            .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(new BackgroundThreadExecutor())
            .build();

    adapter.setList(pagedList);
```

DataSource

public class DataClassKeyed extends KeyedDataSource {

```
@Override
public Integer getKey(@NonNull ModelClass modelClass) {

    return modelClass.id;
}

@Override
public List<WorkOrder> loadInitial(int pageSize) {

    //query which sets data in list and
    return list;
}

@Override
public List<ModelClass> loadBefore(@NonNull Integer id, int pageSize) {
    //query which sets data in list
    return list;
}

@Override
public List<ModelClass> loadAfter(@Nullable Integer id, int pageSize) {
    // Return items adjacent to 'id'
    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: Yes I am using pagedListAdapter.